# How to get the current year select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i need to get the current year it should be start from 2015, till current year, according to years changes also should be make a list of the passed year from the 2015 which is started

```
 <%= select_tag "leave_emp_year", options_for_select(Date.today, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => 8.years.from_now.years), prompt: "Select Year", class: "leave_emp_sort_filter",style: "width:150px !important;" %>
```

> previously i was have done like this

```
<%= select_tag "leave_emp_year", options_for_select([[2016, 2016], [2017, 2017]]), prompt: "Select Year", class: "leave_emp_sort_filter",style: "width:150px !important;" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
<%= select_tag "leave_emp_year", options_for_select(2015..Date.today.year), prompt: "Select Year", class: "leave_emp_sort_filter",style: "width:150px !important;" %>
```

It will give you a select tag as follows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is what you need. Current Year will be selected by default.

```
 <%= select_tag "leave_emp_year", options_for_select(2015..Date.today.year, Date.today.year), prompt: "Select Year", class: "leave_emp_sort_filter",style: "width:150px !important;" %>
```